# Zend Framework exception of invalid controller in netbeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

i had created one project in localhost and all my requests are redirected to htdocs/index.php file. by link http://localhost/TestProject/
the code in index.php is

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
echo $controller->getControllerDirectory();
$controller->setControllerDirectory('/var/www/TestProject/include/Controllers');
$controller->dispatch();
```

all the controllers resides in include directory.
i had created to controllers one in IndexController.php and other is TestController.php
and in those files i had created two actions indexAction() and displayAction()

here is code for IndexController.php

```
Class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "Index Index Jamla";
    }
    public function displayAction(){
        echo "Index Display Jamla";
    }
}
```

now whenever i access http://localhost/TestProject/
it shows following exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with 
message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in /usr/share/php/ 
libzend-frameworkphp/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248 `enter code here`
Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /var/www/TestProject/htdocs/index.php(14):
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 {main} thrown in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework
php/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 248
```

thnkx for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an exception thrown while the request is dispatched. The framework tries then to load the `error` controller, which I guess does not exist in your `include/Controllers` directory. This is why there's the `error` in the message `"Invalid controller specified (error)"`.

There are many reasons why the framework would throw an exception but my first guess would be that you have not defined any view scripts. Thus they fail to load and this will raise the exception.

You have two possibilities:

- Create the view script in the appropriate place. For the index Action of the Index Controller that would be `include/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`. The path is by default `$yourControllerDir . "/../views/scripts/{$controllerName}/{$actionName}.phtml"` (in pseudocode).
- Disable the default rendering of the view script using the following code:

  ```
  // ... your original code
  $controller->setParam('noViewRenderer', true); // disable view rendering
  $controller->dispatch();
  ```

Comment: thnx for the solution it worked for me by setting params in no view renderer